# How can I make a single modifier key into a hotkey by double-tapping it?

Tags: keyboard

In Alfred, a modifier key can be double-tapped to bring Alfred's search bar.

I want to double-tap my modifier keys to switch desktops.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried QMK's 'tap dance' but it is too advanced for this noob.

Comment: Karabinier https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/ allows you to do this

Comment: I tried to do set it up, but it when i press the hotkey (and it changes desktops) it takes the app that my mouse is over to the next desktop...??